# javascript don't show alert when I use a javascript:window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to create a link that when clicked won't redirect but will perform an action and then refresh the page using jquery.

```
<a href="link.php?id=1" id="btnClick">Click Me</a>

<Span id="updateMe">1</span>
```

Jquery

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(e){
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(){
            alert("succes alert 1 worked");
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "another_url.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("#updateMe").html(data);
        }
    });
    javascript:window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` and you should put your redirect in the `success` callback as it will fire right away otherwise.

Comment: this has nothing to do with php

Comment: Because the page exits and the calls have not come back. Also the label `javascript:` is useless.

Comment: What are you expecting by updating `span` content if you are refreshing the page?!? Doesn't really make sense. So why would you need to refresh the page?!

Comment: step1: learn javascript here: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Comment: step2: learn jQuery here: http://try.jquery.com/

Comment: @A. Wolff.  The above code is just a sample code of what I want to achieve not the main code. As you can see there are two links in the ajax request. I want the first link to add an item to database. While the second link sends a message and then updates the span content

Answer (score 0):

Do these:

1. Add `e.preventDefault();` to stop reload.
2. Move `reload()` to the `success` callback.
3. Get rid of `javascript:`. You are already inside it.

**Corrected Code:**

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  url = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function() {
      alert("succes alert 1 worked");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "another_url.php",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#updateMe").html(data);
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Still going to have an issue and the alert is not going to fire and either is the reload. The reason: The OP is clicking a link. The link will navigate. Plus there are two Ajax calls so you have a race condition there also... The correct answer will require promises and canceling the link click.

Comment: @epascarello Agreed. What's the best way then? I am removing my answer.

Comment: Wrap the two Ajax calls in $.when().then()